# SSRS 2008 r2 Export to Excel hiding one column?

Tags: ssrs-2008

i developed some reports and used in data driven subscription to export to excel automatically at a scheduled interval.

my export to excel functionality is working fine and all reports are going to windows shared location.
now actual issue is , my client is not able to down load the file with his program and he faced some problem like i have to fix the issue in ssrs side itself.

AFTER exporting to excel my report contains complete data after report data one column is hiding. i.e

assume my report contain the data for a,b,c columns.if export the data to excel my report contains a,b,c columns and then e,f,g,h.....  i.e here d column is hiding.

it means after completion of report data in excel next column is hiding.

how do i fix it.

thanks in advance

Comment: When you view the report through the report viewer in Internet Explorer does it contain all the columns or is the same one missing?

Answer (score 3):

The export feature does its best to match the report formatting. When you have objects on the report that are not exactly lined up, it uses hidden columns in excel to try to account for the space. There are two things you can do to avoid this.

1. Make sure all the objects (textboxes, tables, etc.) are lined up exactly. You should see a blue highlight when the edges snap together.
2. Resize the objects to use rounded measurements like .25in instead of .249678in.

These steps help the export map the fields directly to cells without having to add additional formatting like hidden columns.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after doing lot of R&D found that all the properties like height width, top, left should be given in points like 28pt instead of 1cm and 72pt instead of 1 inch.

Also main thing is that your column should be in order.

Row1 - Column1 (width 28pt, top 0pt, left 0pt,height 25pt) 
       Column2 (width 26pt, top 1pt, left 0pt,height 23pt)
Row2 - Column1 (width 27pt, top 0pt, left 0pt,height 25pt) 
       Column2 (width 26pt, top 1pt, left 0pt,height 23pt)

Here the problem will be created. Since height of columns of Row 1 are not equal row merge will happen. Similarly width of row1 column1 and row2 column2 are not equal column merge will happen. On top of that when column or row merge is there then wrap text property wont work by default in excel. So even if you give grow column to true in rdl, it will not work.

Note: Avoid cm and inches and give properties in pts.

Regards

Prabhu Palaniappan

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem whereby the first column of my report was being hidden when exporting to Excel.  It was possible to show it by clicking on the column group buttons on the exported report, it seems that Excel creates little numbered buttons above the report, I've only ever seen them for row groupings before, but this report had them for columns too. So, I could show the column, it wasn't missing, but by default it was not showing.

It turned out that the details group in my report had a cell in the second column as its toggle item, I have done this before and not had any problems (most likely in SSRS 2005!), but switching the toggle item of the details group to the the first column cell rather than the second column cell fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I removed the problem is:
1. matching the page header width with the table width.
2. deleting all other contents (like textbox) which appears in header. If these information are essential to place, then you can move it to footer.
3. Starting the tablix row from 0,0 position